# proxy server configuration

Tags: java, apache, proxy, httpserver

I am assigned to implement (or better configure) a kind of http proxy server. The server should support processes like described below:

-A user opens an URL in his browser which has the following structure: http://:/resource_name

-Proxy server validates the resource name in the URL of the incoming http-request and determines the URL of a web-resource it should forward the original request from the client to

-Proxy server forwards the original request, waits until it gets an answer from the external web-server, and posts it back to the user

I'm working within java, but I wouldn't like to implement a proxy server by myself playing with sockets. Instead I'd like to use an apache http server. Does anybody know if its possible to accomplish such a task on the configuration level using apache http server? If so, how?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: What is the validation of the URL that you want to do? Is it something you can put into the apache configuration (e.g. what URLs are valid)? Also, if apache proxies your incorrect request forward to the app-server, it will get something like a 404 or 500 back and it can return this to the user - does this cover your requirement, or do you need to catch the incorrect URL before it gets to the app-server?

Comment: Validation may be not the right term. What I want to do here, is to hide external web-resources from user behind my proxy-server. The user should be able request a resourct from my proxy in the following way: http://my-proxy/resource_name, my proxy should map this url into an url like http://real-resource-provider/resource_name, make a request to the real provider on the web and return the response from the real provider to the user. If the real resourct provider returns http error code like 404, the proxy should retranslate it to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Apache using the modules mod_proxy (to proxy your requests forward) and mod_rewrite (to map your external URL to the URL on your application server)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1):

Apache is not written in java. Your chances are good with [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) or [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).

You will need to implement a webapp with a Servlet intercepting all requests and then handle all your custom logic in the Servlet.

Comment: "Apache is not written in java"
Well, it's not a problem. There are no restrictions on technology the server uses.
"You will need to webapp with a Servlet intercepting all requests and then handle all your custom logic in the Servlet."
So, you think it's impossible to solve the problem on the configuration level of an http server like apache?

Comment: Definitely not impossible, not sure how funny a stuff he wants to do in there. I hope you can do all of that with even Squid.